# Django Rest Framework Paginate By Specified GET Parameter

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST Framework and I need to paginate a list based on a GET parameter provided with the request.

I know that I can set `'PAGINATE_BY': 10` in the settings, however I want to allow the caller to specify the number they want to paginate by when making the request.

I currently have the following serializer:

```
from api.models import Countries
from rest_framework import serializers

class CountrySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    country_geoname_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    country_code = serializers.CharField(source="iso", max_length=2L, required=True)
    country_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=64L, required=True)

    def transform_iso(self, obj, value):
        return "country_code"
```

And I have tried the following view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def country_list(request):
    """
    List all countries
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Countries.objects.all()
        serializer = CountrySerializer(queryset, many=True, data=request.DATA)
        paginate_by = request.GET.get('limit', 10)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

However I feel I am missing something, and I have been unable to figure it out from the documentation.

Should I be doing the pagination in the serializer or in the view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [DRF pagination section](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination.html)? It clearly explains how to paginate data.

Comment: Above link is broken. Same page here : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: Hey @MarkWinterbottom I have added a late (only by 4 years) answer. Have a look

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's break the problem down:

1. You need to create a pagination method that allows the user to define the page size:

   As stated in the [`PageNumberPagination`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) in the DRF documentation, you can define a parameter name by overriding the `page_size_query_param`:

   > If set, this is a string value indicating the name of a query parameter that allows the client to set the page size on a per-request basis. Defaults to `None`, indicating that the client may not control the requested page size.

   You can achieve that by one of the following ways:

   - In `settings.py` add the following:

     ```
     REST_FRAMEWORK = {
         'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
         'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
         'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size'
     }
     ```
   - Or you can create a custom pagination class and override your settings there:

     ```
     from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

     class MyPagination(PageNumberPagination):
         page_size = 10
         page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
     ```
2. Finally you need to define which pagination class you will use in your view function.

   *The following example will work for either of the aforementioned cases by just changing the value of the `paginator` variable to `PageNumberPaginator` or `MyPaginator`:*

   ```
   from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

   @api_view(['GET'])
   def country_list(request):
   """
   List all countries
   """
   if request.method == 'GET':
       paginator = PageNumberPagination()
       queryset = Countries.objects.all()
       context = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
       serializer = CountrySerializer(context, many=True)
       return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
   ```

Now you have function based view with pagination and a query parameter to change the page size.

Comment: Excellent !  is there any way to retrieve the `page_size` value from `MyPagination` class itself and return an error if exceeds the limit ? I ask this because i don't want to validate it on each `view` or `viewSet`

Comment: @Juan-Kabbali Thank you! Yes if you are creating an instance of `MyPagination` class you can retrieve the attribute's value by dot-notation: `my_pagination_instance.page_size`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `PAGINATE_BY_PARAM` setting. This snippet should get you pretty close:

```
class CountryListView(ListAPIView):
    model = Countries
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    paginate_by_param = 'limit'
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination#pagination-in-the-generic-views

My snippet uses generic views to take a lot of the repetition out, I recommend giving those a look, too. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views